# Rails Includes with ordering not by ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple include statement in my controller but the order for the included table is by default id.
In my case I need to order the element in the same way as the uuid is received.

Query:

```
compare_uuids = {xyz, ytb, tyd}
@books = Book.where(uuid: compare_uuids).includes(:venue, :related_publisher, :related_author)
```

The above expression is responding well but say if the uuid ordering with their id are as:

```
id     uuid
5      xyz
1      ytb
2      tyd
```

The expressions that make up when the statement run is order by id. So the uuid order is lost.
Is there any work around to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this...

```
has_many :books, :order => 'priority DESC'
```

In rails 4 this is now deprecated, the new approach would be

```
has_many :books, -> { order(:priority => :desc) }
```

Get output:

you can try

```
Authors.books.except(:order).order('priority DESC')
# OR
Authors.books.reorder('priority DESC')
```

Comment: I added the above line in Book.rb model ... But it is not working

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi are you check that?